# NetBeans JTable without Scroll Pane, Keep Header

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, jtableheader

I'm attempting to add a JTable with NetBeans GUI builder.  The table is inside a panel which already has a scroll bar.  Netbeans automatically creates all JTables inside of a JScrollPane.

However, I want the table to scroll as part of a larger page.  I do not need two scroll bars.

My problem is: if I get rid of the scroll pane, I lose the header.

Is there a way to have a table with a header inside the Netbeans GUI builder?

Comment: Not easily from within the form designer....

Comment: That’s an artificial problem: if the layout manager of the surrounding panel gives the scroll pane the space it wants (which defaults to the preferred size of its contents), the scrollbar will not show up unless the vertical scrollbar policy is set to “always”. See [JScrollPane.verticalScrollBarPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#verticalScrollBarPolicy): the default is `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED`. So you don’t need to manipulate the `JScrollPane` at all to get the desired behavior. Just an appropriate layout for the parent panel.

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is: if I get rid of the scroll pane, I lose the header.

- `JTableHeader` is (automatically) visible in the case that `JTable` is inside `JScrollPane`
- you have to get `JTableHeader` from `JTable` and place this Object programatically by using `LayoutManager` to the container, I'm strongly recommend to use `BorderLayout` or `GridBagLayout` for this container

Answer (score 1):

If you add `JTabel` directly to container(not to `JScrollPane`) you need to add `JTableHeader` by yourself(programatically ), try next example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JTable t = new JTable(new Object[][]{{1,2,3}},new Object[]{"1","2","3"});
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(t.getTableHeader(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(t);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

[image]